# How to use a message from one select menu in another

Tags: python, discord.py

In the "log" menu, the user has selected an action, I need to get a message in the "channel" menu that the user has selected in the "log".

I couldn't have done it myself

```
class log(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Логи сервера"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Логи входа и выхода участников")
            ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите раздел.",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options, custom_id="LOG")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            if self.values[0] == "Логи сервера":
                await interaction.response.edit_message(view=channel_log())
            if self.values[0] == "Логи входа и выхода участников":
                await interaction.response.edit_message(view=channel_log())
```

```
class channel(discord.ui.ChannelSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите раздел.",channel_types=[discord.ChannelType.text], custom_id="HELP")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        #for self.values[0] in logs():
            print()
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO logs (message_log) VALUES ({self.values[0].id})')
            conn.commit()
            await interaction.response.edit_message(f"{self.values[0].id}")
            return
```

A person in the log menu selects a specific action, how to take what the user has selected in the log in the channel menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can just the message as an argument to the `ChannelLog` class.
Something like that:

```py
class Log(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Логи сервера"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Логи входа и выхода участников")
        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите раздел.",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options, custom_id="LOG")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
         view = discord.ui.View()
         view.add_item(ChannelLog(self.values[0]))
         await interaction.response.edit_message(view=view)


class ChannelLog(discord.ui.ChannelSelect):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите раздел.",channel_types=[discord.ChannelType.text], custom_id="HELP")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        #for self.values[0] in logs():
            print()
            cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO logs (message_log) VALUES ({self.values[0].id})')
            conn.commit()
            await interaction.response.edit_message(f"{self.values[0].id}")
            # do something with the message
            print(self.message)
            return
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'channel' object has no attribute 'to_components'

Comment: This is another error in your code. You didn't use views, but components like views. I'm fixing this in the part where I create the view and add the ChannelLog component